# Control reaches end of non void function after switch case statement

Tags: c++, enums, switch-statement

I have a piece of code where I do a switch case statement for all the values of an enum class. All the branches have a return statement, but the gcc (at leat 10.5 and trunk) still thinks that the control can reach the end of the function. Same code compiles fine with clang 16.

Is this correct or a bug in gcc?

```
#include <cassert>

enum class C
{
    A, B
};

int foo()
{
    C c;
    switch (c) {
        case C::A:
          assert(false);
        case C::B:
          return 0;
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/v3K6jx5aG

Comment: Your `swirch` in that function never returns anything if the value passed to the function is not one of the `case` statements. The compiler is right to complain . Btw; the function doesn't take any values and the switch just operates on the default constructed value of `c` - what's the point?

Comment: The varaible `c` is not initialized, so what is the value?

Comment: An enum is technically allowed to store a value other than one of the enum vlue, as long as the underlying type can represent the value. You could have `C c = static_cast<C>(42);` and your function would reach the end without hitting a `return`

Comment: @JesperJuhl it covers all the possible values in the enum class. The code is just for example purposes, the real code I have is more complex, and uses c inside the case statements. Not that it matters

Comment: @BoP it should be initialized to first enum value, no?

Comment: Not unless you say so. Otherwise it is like `int x;` - uninitialized.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux its not an enum, but an enum class. Are enum classes still allow to have other values? That means that adding a `default` case should cover those cases, no?

Comment: @jjcasmar Adding `class` to `enum` makes it a scoped enum, the enum values need to be qualified with the enum type. It prevents them from being dumped into the encompassing namespace. With or without `class` an `enum` is allowed to have a value other than one of its enum values. Adding `default` will fix your problem, but introduces the problem of what to do in that case.

Comment: Better to add the error handling _after_ the switch, because a `default` label will inhibit compiler warnings about unhandled values.

Comment: Just because it's a enum doesn't mean that it cannot have values outside the declared ones

Answer (score 5):

> Is this correct or a bug in gcc?

This is correct.

`enum` is an `int` (or another integral type), it can store any integer. An uninitialized enum `c` can have like any value, also different from all enumerator list elements.

Note that *your code* is incorrect. The sole *act of reading* the uninitialized value of `c` inside `switch (c)` is making your code have technically undefined behavior.

Producing, or not, a warning about reading an uninitialized value or about a control flow potentially reaching the end of a non-void function is up to the good will of the compiler, it is not something required. It is a quality of implementation issue.

Comment: So its a bug in clang?

Comment: the bug is not initializing `c` which causes undefined behavior right away. Not returning for all values is only warning because only potentially UB

Comment: @jjcasmar What would be the bug in clang?

Comment: *" An uninitialized enum c can have any value"* An uninitialized variable has an indeterminate value which is different from "any value". If it had "any value" then `c == c` would be `true` but it is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Clang accepts the code without warning

Comment: That's great. A warning is _not_ something that compiler _has to_ produce (let's say, in this case). Compiler can print you a wall of warnings, or print you nothing. It is up to compiler writer if he _wants_ to print such warning or not. I wouldn't say it is a bug, it is a missing feature.

Comment: @jjcasmar turn on the warnings then clang will complain as well https://godbolt.org/z/4ebK5KMYs

Comment: @jjcasmar well ok, it does not complain about the missing return https://godbolt.org/z/d7KcrKjnn. That doesnt make the code less wrong though

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub